# generate (overlapping) sets of mutually similar elements from binary similarity matrix

Tags: r, set, cluster-analysis

Given a symmetric binary similarity matrix **`M`** (`1` = similarity), I want to extract all (potentially overlapping) subsets, where all elements within a set are mutually similar.

```
  A B C D E
A 1 1 0 0 0
B 1 1 1 1 0
C 0 1 1 1 1
D 0 1 1 1 1
E 0 0 1 1 1
```

Also, sets contained within other sets should be discarded (e.g. `{D,E}` is contained in `{C,D,E}`). For the matrix the result would be: `{A,B}`, `{B,C,D}`, `{C,D,E}`

1. **How can I easily achieve this?**
2. **I suspect that there is some clustering algorithm for this, but I am unaware of the name for these types of problems. To which (mathematical) class of problems does this task belong to?**

**Code**

```
M <- matrix(c(1,1,0,0,0,
              1,1,1,1,0,
              0,1,1,1,1,
              0,1,1,1,1,
              0,0,1,1,1), ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE)
colnames(M) <- rownames(M) <- LETTERS[1:5]
```

*PS. While this may smell like some homework assignment, but its actually a problem I encountered in my job :)*

Comment: does `igraph::max_cliques(g, min=2)` do what you want?

Comment: Related: [Generating distinct groups of nodes in a network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55910373/generating-distinct-groups-of-nodes-in-a-network). You may start with `g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(M)`

Comment: Yes, this appears to be exactly what I was looking for. Do you want to turn this into an answer?

Answer (score 4):

A **clique** is a subgraph that is completely connected.

What you are looking for is hence (maximal) **clique detection**.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem

Beware that the results can be much larger than you anticipate. Consider a graph where each edge is 1 with a probability of p. For p close to 1, almost any subset is a clique. Finding maximum cliques then becomes expensive. P can also be chosen to maximize the number of maximal cliques...